# copy a MySQL table which has data in ibdata file

Tags: mysql, database-administration, data-recovery

I have a database in MySQL with several tables. Some of the tables only have .frm files. Some have .frm .mdy .mdi I believe data for the .frm tables is in the ibdata file.

There is a lot of data in all the tables and I can see it.

How do I make a duplicate of this database with a different name? I can copy the folder and rename, but the tables with just the .frm files don't have the data.

Is there an easy simple way I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CREATE TABLE student2 SELECT * FROM student

edit: into a new database CREATE TABLE newdatabase.student2 SELECT * FROM olddatabase.student

Comment: That will do it in the same database, i want to e able to copy the table into a new database

Comment: CREATE TABLE newdatabase.student2 SELECT * FROM olddatabase.student

Comment: Error Code: 1146Table newdatabase.student2 doesnt exist

Comment: Thats the error i get

Comment: i worked out a way around if i create the table and then do an insert into like you shown instead of create it works